# Want to set up a timed watering system for 'remote' garden patches without utilizing underground water hoses

Tags: watering

I would like to set up a timer-based watering system for my mother's garden (see figure below). I plan to have the timer installed on the main water supply line, which then branches via underground hoses that have sprinklers installed at intervals.

The problem with this approach is that I cannot account for Remote Patches A and C (not sure if the term "island" is appropriate here) without resorting to digging up some of the front yard paved bricks to install the water lines.

I guess an on-the-ground hose would be borderline acceptable for Remote Patch C, but the main gate makes things difficult with Remote Patch A.

Is there a way to water the remote patches without having to resort to laying underground lines/removing paved bricks across the gate? I'm open to all suggestions.

[image: Garden Layout]

Comment: If the fence and gate are high enough you could tie the hose above them. Similar to how a you would staple an ethernet or power cord above a doorframe in an apartment.

Comment: How about putting an arbor over the gate, putting the hose (and a heating cable) over that, then growing some flowering vines on it. A lot of work, but attractive and functional.

Answer (score 2):

Don't be too quick to rule out underground pipe. You don't have to dig up your bricks. We were taught to handle this situation by putting garden hose to the pvc pipe and boring underneath. Here's an example: https://youtu.be/3Kv9x8bAWVM?t=1m23s

Answer (score 1):

How about a sprinkler aimed from Patch B? What I did was run a 1" PVC line under the ground to span the gate, then attached hoses to that on the vertical legs that came up from the ground. You can get pipe thread and hose thread, or use converters, to cement on the end of PVC pipe. I did a lot of sprinkler system modification on my house of three years, as we added our own gardening area. I converted sprinkler heads to hose compatible stubs, in order to run soaker hoses, and the like.

Comment: Putting it underground wasn't an option, as he didn't want to dig up the patio pavers.